# How to return multiple rows by combining two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The following is a simplification of my problem, for the purposes of this question. I've two tables.

Table profile:

```
TABLE profile
profile_id  | first_name    | last_name
1           | David         | Battery
2           | John          | Motor
```

Table known_names:

```
TABLE known_names
profile_id  | first_name
1           | A
1           | B
1           | C
2           | X
2           | Y
2           | X
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to output known_names.first_name alongside profile.last_name when profile.profile_id = known_names.profile_id. BUT I also want to print out profile.first_name and profile.last_name in one of the rows in the result.

So the query may look like this (syntax is wrong, and I'm looking for the correct query to do this):

```
SELECT profile_id, first_name, last_name FROM profile CROSS JOIN known_names ON known_names.profile_id = profile.profile_id WHERE profile.first_name = 'David'
```

An example of the result is:

```
profile_id  | first_name    | last_name
1           | David         | Battery
1           | A             | Battery
1           | B             | Battery
1           | C             | Battery
```

How could I write a query that could achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this::

```
   Select t.profileId, t.firstName, t.lastName
    FROM
(
SELECT 
        p.profile_id as profileId, 
        p.first_name as firstName, 
        p.first_name as first_Name,
        p.last_name as lastName
        FROM profile p

    UNION 

        SELECT 
        p.profile_id as profileId, 
        k.first_name as firstName,
        p.first_name as first_Name,
        p.last_name as lastName 
        FROM profile p, 
        known_names k
        WHERE  k.profile_id = p.profile_id
) t
where t.first_Name='David'
```

Check the [SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39eb3/36)

Comment: Thanks, but this is basically an `INNER JOIN` which isn't what I'm looking for, as the inner join won't print out the p.first_name, k.first_name as different rows in the result.

Comment: Thanks, it answers my question, but is there a way to not have to write `AND p.first_name = 'David'` twice? I ask this because the actual problem requires about 5-10 `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: Thanks, I'm surprised MySQL didn't use a temporary table for it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use profile_id as an input to the query rather than first_name:

```
SELECT
  p.profile_id AS profileId,
  p.first_name AS firstName,
  p.last_name AS lastName
  FROM profile p
  WHERE p.profile_id = 1

UNION

SELECT
  k.profile_id AS profileId,
  k.first_name AS firstName,
  p.last_name AS lastName
  FROM known_names k
  INNER JOIN profile p ON p.profile_id = k.profile_id
  WHERE k.profile_id = 1
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa421/18

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit that I don't use often a [GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html), but I wanted to use it to answer your question without using a UNION query:

```
SELECT
  profile_id,
  COALESCE(first_name_k, first_name_p) First_Name,
  Last_Name
FROM (
  SELECT 
    p.profile_id, 
    k.first_name as first_name_k,
    p.first_name as first_name_p,
    p.last_name 
  FROM
    profile p inner join known_names k
    ON k.profile_id = p.profile_id
  WHERE
    p.first_name='David'
  GROUP BY
    p.profile_id,
    k.first_name WITH ROLLUP
  ) s
WHERE
  profile_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  first_name_k IS NOT NULL,
  COALESCE(first_name_k, first_name_p)
```

See it working [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1ac7/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.first_name other_FirstName
FROM    profile a
        INNER JOIN known_names b
            ON a.profile_ID = b.profile_ID
// WHERE a.first_Name = ''
ORDER BY a.profile_id, a.first_Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39eb3/4)

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    profile a
WHERE   first_name = 'david'
UNION
SELECT  c.profile_id, c.first_name, d.last_name
FROM    profile b
        INNER JOIN known_names c
            ON b.profile_ID = c.profile_ID
        CROSS JOIN 
       (
          SELECT  last_Name
          FROM    profile 
          WHERE   first_name = 'david'
       ) d
WHERE   b.first_name = 'david'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39eb3/9)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having to duplicate the WHERE clauses?